# SQL Query select max value unless not null from two tables with intersection

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Tables:

```
Files
-------------------
id | revision
-------------------
1 | 0
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 0
2 | 1

Folders
-----------------
id | name
-----------------
1 | FooBar

Shares
--------------------------------
id | folderId | fileId | fileRev
--------------------------------
1  |     1    |    1   |   null
2  |     1    |    2   |    0
```

The output I am expecting:

```
fileId | revision
------------------
 1     |     2
 2     |     0
```

I want to be able to take the information based on the Shares table and if the file revision is NULL, return the record of that file with the highest revision. If fileRev is not null, return the file record that corresponds with that revision.

I've been able to replicate it like so:

```
SELECT f.id, max(f.rev) as rev
FROM files f
INNER JOIN shares s ON s.fileId = f.id
WHERE s.fileRev IS NULL AND s.folderId = 1
GROUP BY f.id
UNION
SELECT f.id, f.rev as rev 
FROM files f
INNER JOIN shares s ON s.fileId = f.id AND f.rev = s.fileRev 
WHERE s.fileRev IS NOT NULL AND s.folderId = 1
```

How can I do this with a more optimized query? Possibly without a union?

Comment: For better answers it's really useful to add an sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) so people can try for themselves with some data available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work, hard to test without the database available.

IFNULL returns either shares.fileRev if it's not null, and if it is it returns files.rev

```
SELECT files.id,
       MAX(IFNULL(shares.fileRev, files.rev)) as rev
FROM files
JOIN shares ON shares.fileId = files.id
WHERE shares.folderId = 1
GROUP BY files.id
```

Comment: Hmm, this is really close. It is only returning the file that has a null revision in the Shares table.

Comment: @Nick, fixed i forgot to group on `files.id`. otherwise it takes the max out of all versions. Maybe you can even remove the `where` seems pointless at the moment? although i don't have the full context.

Try it again, i edited my answer.

Comment: The where is important since I am trying to find all file shares within a folder. But this appears to be giving me the results that I want. Much simpler than my query. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, try and lookup the commands i used to get a better understanding of how it works :) glad to be of help! if you have some more trouble feel free to tag me

Comment: Will do @Jester. I had no idea IFNULL existed and was exactly what I was looking for. (I'm new to MySQL, coming from SQL Server.)

Comment: COALESCE conforms to the ANSI standard